# how to remove text after occurence of a character

Tags: c#

I have a string that I want to remove some characters from
I want all % symbols and the character directly following that character to be removed
e.g. `Apple%j pie` turns into `Apple pie`
I want it to do this several times too, so  `Chicken%f and%f waffles` turns into `Chicken and waffles`

Comment: Split words (string.Split), search char on each word (string.IndexOf), keep only the wanted text (string.Substring), rejoin the words (string.Join). Now you could start to write some code

Comment: `var output = Regex.Replace(input, @"%.", "");`. If you _also_ want to remove '%' when it's at the end of the string, use `%.?` instead of `%.`.

Answer (score 3):

Use regex matching a percent sign then any character:

```
var result = Regex.Replace("Chicken%f and%f waffles", @"%.", "");
//Chicken and waffles
```